# Computing the Value of n for algorithmic equation

Tags: computer-science, radix

I am working on This question. Have Solved many of them But stuck with the Computation of n^n = 10^7..
How should i Evaluate above for the value of n..
The original Question is :-

Assume you have two computers, CA and CB, capable of performing 10^7 and
10^9 operations per second, respectively. Both computers run a set of algorithms whose
precise complexities f(n) are given below. Determine the size n of the biggest input that
can be processed in 1 second for each computer, as in the example.
[image]

The precise complexity tells you how many operations are performed to solve an instance
of size n. Assume each operation takes the same time and that the input sizes are natural
numbers 1, 2, 3, . . .
The point of this exercise is to see how much can we gain by going from CA to CB.

Any comments will be appreciated for the evaluating n^n = 10^7 ....
Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [cs.se]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asking for someone else to do their homework.

Comment: You need to solve 9 equations for CA and CB. In your example: sqrt(n) = 10^7 (CA, 10^7^2), and sqrt(n) = 10^9 (CB, 10^9^2). Find n.

Comment: No sir i am not asking for any sort of Homework solution.. I am just asking for to explain me the question and how the example is solved in the question .. Just

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematical functions, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have number of operations (per second).

The function maps input size to number of operations.

So all we need to do is set that function equal to the number of operations, and calculate `n`.

> sqrt(n) = 10<sup>7</sup>
>
> sqrt(n)<sup>2</sup> = (10<sup>7</sup>)<sup>2</sup>
>
> n = 10<sup>14</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this explanation sir, I don't know why people over here instead of understanding the problem with user just de-rate the question.

Comment: Now i understood the problem and solving my homework by myself. Really Thank you so much

Comment: Sir Can you confirm me that the solution for fist row will be 10^700 and 10^900 respectively. According to me this is the solution for first row.

Comment: Actually it's quite a bit more than that. To take the `lg` out, you need to take 10 (assume log base 10) to the power whatever's on the other side.